# How to make double-quotes autoclose with vim-autoclose

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose.

By default, double-quotes (`"`) are not auto-closed as in "string". How can I make it autoclose?

As mentioned in the docs, I tried adding this to my vimrc:

```
let g:AutoClosePairs_add = "\""
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the documentation and issues regarding the plugin that you're using, it seems to me that the plugin is not well maintained. I strongly suggest you to try out [autopairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) which has been working really good for me.

**And i think the reason why you are not being able to get double quotes autoclose is due to an existing [issue within the plugin](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose/pull/67).**

Hope this helps you somehow.